# Calling scenario from different feature file using another variable

Tags: karate

I have feature file with a scenario that uses a variable eg: 1. 
I am calling this scenario from another feature file but this time I want to pass another variable eg: 2

Feature file A: generateDocument.feature

```
@generatedoc
Scenario: Verify able to generate document for user
    Given path somepath
    And header Content-Type = 'application/json'
    And request {"userId": "abc123"}
    When method POST
    Then status 200
    * table documentId
      | id         | docTitle | 
      | '#notnull' | "ijk"    | 
      | '#notnull' | "xyz"    | 
    And match response[*].id == $documentId[*].id
    And match response[*].title == $documentId[*].docTitle
```

Feature file B: useDocument.feature

```
call read('generateDocument.feature@generatedoc') { userId: 'abc456'}
```

So when I run feature file A, it should use the variable 'abc123', but when I run the feature file B, it should use the variable 'abc456'

But currently when I run feature file B, it still uses 'abc123'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do this in A - so it becomes a re-usable feature.

```
And request {"userId": "#(userId)"}
```

Now you need to call it 2 times (maybe in 2 different features and it will work):

Feature B:

```
call read('generateDocument.feature') { userId: 'abc456' }
```

Feature C:

```
call read('generateDocument.feature') { userId: 'abc123' }
```